# Fluid Sim not reacting at all

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have created a simple scene of a lollipop bouncing thru a puddle. It worked once but I wanted to increase the resolution and tweak some settings. So I started with a new domain and water object.

But, there is no interaction after baking. I have tried changing the size of the domain and resetting things, but it still won't create the fluid interaction object.

I tried to see what other people were doing and followed Blender Guru and Sardi Pax's videos but nothing works.

What am I doing wrong? (also how do I upload the darned blend file?)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzbpekym81ummu1/fluid%20test.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fluid film is too thin so that no fluid particles are created. Make it a bit thicker and it works.

Comment: Thank you! Of course. the one thing I didn't test...